# Populate Text Box with Dropdown and pass multiple variables to form(javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have a Dropdown menu that is loaded with user names from a database. I want to populate the users balance into the textbox below it when a name is selected. I am able to pass the current dropdown value to the below text box with the following code, but I need to be able to maintain the value of the dropdown value(user_id) to pass to the form. I know very little javascript; hoping someone can give me a hand.

Thanks.

```
function set_to(id)
{
$('#private_list').val(id);

}


<div class="wrapper container">
<div class="row">
<div id="loginbox" class="mainbox col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<div class="panel panel-default" >
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="panel-title text-center"><strong>Adjust Balance</strong>       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body" >
    <form action="adjust_balance" name="adjust_balance" id="login-form" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

  <option value="" disabled selected>Select User Name</option>
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span> 
      <select class="form-control" name="id" onchange="javascript:set_to(this.value);"">
        <?php
         foreach($users as $row){
          echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->first_name.' '.$row->last_name.'</option>';
        }
        ?>                          


      </select>
</div>

<div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-usd"></i></span>
        <input id="private_list" type="text" id="private_list" name="balance" class="form-control" name="balance" value="" placeholder="Balance">
      </div>       
<br>
<br>

      <div class="form-group">
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
        <!--<button type="submit" href="#private_list" class="btn btn-success pull-left"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Load List</button>-->
          <button type="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-success pull-right">   <i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Update User Balance</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So let me get this straight. You are writing a financial App of some sort and there is a page where I can see ALL THE NAMES OF ALL YOUR CLIENTS and then you will show me their balances. **Give me strength** _That sounds like a nice head start for al the hackers_

Comment: No its a pickup hockey app for my buddies and I. I am sick of collecting money each game so i want to be able to just adjust there balance. If someone wants to hack my private pickup hockey app it wouldn't be the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

you have to send a ajax request to your controller with user-id in the data .At the server side you will get this user-id and make query which will give you required result against that user.Now you have to populate that record in select options and echo them.You will get these options in success data .Then simply you have to put these options in select.

```
 $('#select-id').change(function (){

    var select-value=$('#select-id').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"url-of-controller",
            data:{user-id:select-value},
            type:"get",
            success:function (data){
               $("#target-select").html(data);
            },
            error:function (err){
               alert(err);
            }



        });

    });
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, just slightly beyond my skill level.

Comment: you have to include  the jquery library .Then this code will work properly .

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with this; probably not the best solution but I have been coding for about a week and it works.

```
$('#userbalanceselector').on('change', function () {
var val = this.value;
var parts = val.split("_");
$('#balance').val(parts[0]);
$('#user_id').val(parts[1]);
});
```